# WP7 ScrollableTextBox

Tags: silverlight, textbox, scroll, windows-phone-7.1

I am looking for solution  of scrollable TextBox on Windows Phone 7.

At this moment I have this XAML code:

```
   <ScrollViewer
        Height="250"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        Padding="0"                         
        Margin="0">
        <TextBox 
             x:Name="Description"
             Text="{Binding Path=LocationInfo.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"
             IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=LocationInfo.IsReadOnly}"                                
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Height="500"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

It works, but when user is typing and visual part of TextBox is full filled, it does not autoscroll. User has to scroll manualy to see the part where he writes.. I need to do some autoscroll behaviour.

Comment: I'd say that this is the wrong approach. Dont make the TextBox 500px high and don't put it into a ScrollViewer. Making it 250px high should work properly. Is there a special reason why you did what you did?

Comment: OK.. TextBox height is perhaps wrong. I put TextBox to ScrollViewer in order to achieve behaviour of Scrollable TextBox - i need to show long description text on the page. But the page is also prepared for inserting/editing, there is the problem that i have described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A was also looking for a solution to this problem... My conclusion was that there is no good solution. My final solution is similar to yours:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" mytoolkit:TextBinding.UpdateSourceOnChange="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text="text" InputScope="Text" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Microsoft has to solve this issue...

See also:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/69286/430208.aspx

[Scrollable TextBox in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576691/scrollable-textbox-in-wp7)