# Can we use “Textarea” tag with scroll in xaml?

Tags: windows-phone-8

```
<ScrollViewer Height="239" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox x:Name="newcTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

with that code phonetextbox is scroll *but* when scrollviewer height is **overflow**. The text is hide and scrollviewer is **"scrolling Up"**

Answer (score 0):

Check out comment of Uday0119's [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5577085/182344).

This comment isn't well formed so below I copy code from my solution.

XAML code:

```
<ScrollViewer
  x:Name="scrollViewer"
  Height="200"
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <toolkit:PhoneTextBox
    x:Name="phoneTextBox"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    TextInputStart="OnTextInputStart"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And C#:

```
private void OnTextInputStart(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  scrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
  scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(phoneTextBox.ActualHeight);
}
```